# How to seperate each TouchableOpacity from state ? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Begginer developer react native.

im dealing with design pattern issue ,
i have multiple TouchableOpacity's in the same component (i have to keep it that way).
for each one i have onPress function thats changs there background and reverse .
the problom is that the function dependent on State current statment and when i click on one of them evreyone is changing .

```
function Grocery({ navigation }) {

  const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(0);
  const onPress = () => setIsPressed(!isPressed);



  return (  
    
    <ScrollView>
      <Button title="home" onPress={() => {FindMatch(GetIngridients());navigation.navigate("MatchedRecipiesScreen");}}>press</Button>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("pasta");onPress();}}  >
    <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
        <Image style={styles.imageright} source={require('../assets/Pastaa.jpg')} />
        <Text> pasta</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>



      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {AddToPanetry("eggs");onPress();}}  >
      <View style={isPressed && styles.pressedButtonStyle} />
        <Image style={styles.imageleft} source={require('../assets/eggs.jpg')} />
        <Text>eggs</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    padding: 50,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  }
  ,
  imageleft: {
    borderRadius:100,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'black',
    height: 120,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 80,
    padding:25
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
   
  },
    tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  pressedButtonStyle: {
    position:"absolute",
    width:150,
    height:121,
    backgroundColor:'black',
    opacity:0.6,
    zIndex:100,
    borderRadius:80
  },
  imageright: {
    borderRadius:100,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'black',
    height: 120,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 80,
    padding:25
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an state array

```
 const [isPressed, setIsPressed ] = useState([true, false, false, false, false]);
```

Here is an [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/toggle-boolean-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, too:

```
 const [isPressed, setIsPressed ] = React.useState('first');
   ...

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setIsPressed('first')>
                <View style={isPressed === 'first' ? styles.pressedButtonStyle : null} />              
        </TouchableOpacity>


   ...
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setIsPressed('second')>
            <View style={isPressed === 'second' ? styles.pressedButtonStyle : null} />              
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: first of all tnx , thats workd just fine but there is a problem when ever one of them is working the other are cancelled . any advice ?

Comment: You can use another useState hook with just a boolean and set it on true whenever onPress action is happening.